# how to extract the numeric information from a list within a dataframe in r?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following type of entries in the first column of a data frame called `dfgModsPepFiltered_subset`:

```
A640-P641 = 456.123x
```

Trying to extract the numeric information from this with the following R script:

```
dfgModsPepFiltered_subset$AA <- regmatches(dfgModsPepFiltered_subset$Peptide,
        gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", dfgModsPepFiltered_subset$Peptide))
```

Gives me:

```
c("640", "641", "453", "123")
```

However, what I really need is a new column for each of `"640"`, `"641"` and `"456.123"`.

I've tried various combinations of unlisting but can't seem to get the format right.

Answer (score 3):

You could modify the `regmatches`

```
 as.data.frame(do.call(`rbind`,
         lapply(regmatches(dfgModsPepFiltered_subset$Peptide,
             gregexpr("[[:digit:].]+", dfgModsPepFiltered_subset$Peptide)), 
                                                        as.numeric))

  #   V1  V2      V3
  #1 640 641 456.123
  #2 620 625 285.400
```

Or using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
res <-  extract(dfgModsPepFiltered_subset, Peptide, c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'),
               '[A-Z](\\d+)-[A-Z](\\d+) += +(\\d+\\.\\d+).+', convert=TRUE) 


res
#  Col1 Col2    Col3
#1  640  641 456.123
#2  620  625 285.400
```

Or you could use the `regex`

```
extract(dfgModsPepFiltered_subset, Peptide, c('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'),
        '[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9]+)[^0-9]+([0-9.]+)[^0-9]+')
```

Or

```
library(splitstackshape)
res1 <-  cSplit(dfgModsPepFiltered_subset, 'Peptide', '[^0-9.]', fixed=FALSE)
res1[,names(res1)[!colSums(is.na(res1))], with=FALSE]
#   Peptide_2 Peptide_4 Peptide_7
#1:       640       641   456.123
#2:       620       625   285.400
```

Or using `strsplit`

```
 as.data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(dfgModsPepFiltered_subset$Peptide,
                       '[^0-9.]'), function(x) na.omit(as.numeric(x)))))

 #   V1  V2      V3
 #1 640 641 456.123
 #2 620 625 285.400
```

#### data

```
dfgModsPepFiltered_subset <- data.frame(Peptide= c('A640-P641 = 456.123x',
       'A620-B625 = 285.400x'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Comprehensive coverage! Very useful. +1

Comment: Any space for `stringi`? I was wondering if `stir_extract_all_regex` would achieve the goal.

Comment: @jazzurro Yes, possibly this `do.call(rbind,lapply(stri_extract_all_regex(dfgModsPepFiltered_subset$Peptide, '[0-9.]+'), as.numeric))`